# Dynamically added ASP.Net Button could not call Click or CommandArgument event

Tags: c#, asp.net, commandargument

I am adding x number of buttons to an asp.net web application. This is my code for doing so:

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var foo in bar){
    Button b = new Button();
    b.ID = "button" + i.ToString();
    b.CommandName = "var_value";
    b.CommandArgument = foo;
    b.Command += Execute_Command;

    //add to panel p
    p.Controls.Add(b);

    i++;
}

private void Execute_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e){
    //do stuff
}
```

The Execute_Command method is never called. The buttons display just fine, and when I debug they have the command name and the correct command argument assigned to them. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons are created dynamically, so ***they are not in the control tree***. As the result, when you trigger a click event, it could not fire Command event.

In order to fix it, you will need to reload the dynamically created buttons in ***Page_Init*** or ***Page_Load*** event on ***every postback*** with ***same IDs***.

For example,

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int i = 0;
   foreach(var foo in bar){
      Button b = new Button();
      b.ID = "button" + i.ToString();
      b.CommandName = "var_value";
      .CommandArgument = foo;
      b.Command += Execute_Command;

      //add to panel p
      p.Controls.Add(b);

      i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked! The method containing this code was called within if(!IsPostBack) Thank you!!